# Compare user response with string using javascript for quizz

Tags: javascript, compare, hamming-distance

I have a input field for the user who's listening a music and try to find the correct artist or track name.

```
<input type="search" id="search" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="search" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
```

i would like to it compare with two javascript variables :

- track_name = "Alicia Keys";
- artist_name = "Fallin'";

The problem is to handle human typing errors.
ex : "alicia key falin" should return true for the artist and the track name.

I have already tried scripts about [Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) and also the [fusejs](http://fusejs.io/) library but i'm not convainced by the result.

Actual tests :

```
function hammingDistance(str1, str2) {
  var dist = 0;
  str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
  str2 = str2.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0, j = Math.max(str1.length, str2.length); i < j; i++) {
    if (!str1[i] || !str2[i] || str1[i] !== str2[i]) {
      dist++;
    }
  }
  return dist;
}
```

The objective being to prevent capital, lower case, hyphen, period, comma, number, featuring, feat, etc. errors.

Is there some librairies or script to handle this properly?

Comment: Have you looked at regular expressions. They seem as if they would suit your needs.

Comment: @JonathanBartlett Regular expressions will work for special characters but for typos?